# Is there any way to check the Governor's daughters' beauty level?

Tags: sid-meiers-pirates

I know this game allows three levels of beauty for the girls but I can I be sure what's the level of the daughter my character is currently dating?

Or in other words: how can I be sure to marry a "beauty"?

Comment: Other than the answers below, the girl's beauty can also be found in the status screen (where all relationships are listed)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can judge the beauty of the governor's daughter by how she dresses.

Plain daughters will wear a scarf that covers almost to their neck:

[image: a plain daughter]

Attractive daughters wear something revealing that covers their shoulders:

[image]

Beautiful daughters wear a very revealing low-cut dress:

[image]

Also, when the daughter enters the room, the text on the screen will describe her as being "rather plain," "attractive," or "beautiful" as the case may be.

[image]

Here again, you can note that her dress gives away her beauty level as well.

Comment: The first thing I typed to answer this was "you can judge beauty by her breast size" and that seemed...  horrible, especially out of context :)  What can I say, the developers of this game had very... particular views about what constitutes beauty.

Comment: Ahah you might not be so far from the truth, historically speaking

Comment: @Emiliano: That depends on which part of history (both in time and in location) you're talking about.  Standards of beauty vary widely, both from time to time and from place to place.

Answer (score 5):

If you look on the map, a city that you have visited will actually have that information in the description.

"The governor's daughter here is usually very -----------"